# To store $rootScope value inside localstorage and using it in another controller on page refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a token generator function,
I have to pass token parameter in every http call , so even on refresh I need to store token value intact and use it.
Here is my code-

```
 $scope.accessTokenFunction=function() { 
      data={

      }
         $http.post('API_url',data, config)
         .success(function(data, status) {

          $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
          $rootScope.access_token=$scope.PostDataResponse.access_token;
          console.log($rootScope.access_token);
           var access_token = $rootScope.access_token
                localStorage.setItem("access_token", access_token);
                localStorage.getItem("access_token");
                console.log(access_token);
                $rootScope.acc=access_token;


    })

 };
```

Problem is var access_token is not able to store $rootscope.access_token on page refresh , but if I use

```
var access_token = 'jack'
I can use this value successfully even on page refresh inside other controllers.
```

What I want is $rootScope value to be assigned to access_token even on page refresh.
Any help is appreciated, thanks

EDIT

I made changes like this
                    var access_token = $scope.access_token

```
                localStorage.data=access_token;
                console.log(localStorage.data);
```

And used this localStorage inside another controller like this

```
myApp.controller().....
{
    $scope.access_token=localstorage.data;

}
```

I can now use this $scope.access_token anywhere in controller with the stored value.

Comment: better to scrap `$rootScope` for passing value and use `$localStorage` instead of only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on page reload your app will get initialized so you will have nothing in your $rootscope. Instead you can store your access token into or session,localstorage etc.

Comment: how to store $rootscope in localstorage ? I stored a string 'jack' successfully but not able to store $rootScope inside localstorage.

Comment: localStorage.setItem('rootScope', JSON.stringify($rootScope));

We need to stringify object. But we have to make sure everytime we update rootscope we have to update localstorage

Comment: But when I refresh the page the $rootScope value is still getting as undefined. Code runs well tilll I don't refresh page

Comment: are you reading values from localstorage or $rootScope? If rootScope it will be undefined. You have to read it from localStorage

Comment: hey thanks , i defined in the controllers localStorage like $scope.access_token= localStorage.data....Then I am able to use it.

Comment: I was so dumb back then, didn't know we could accept an answer by clicking on tick :D

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Can you provide a plunkr for your code.

One more thing, what is the type is your `access_token`? 
I guess, you know, you need to stringify JSON Objects before saving to localStorage and parse it when pulling it back.

Also, I guess, you should use sessionStorage, rather than localStorage.